# Open and save Word doc with Excel VBA doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to open a Word doc, paste data from my Excel file and then save that Word document.

Opening Word and pasting the data works fine, but it doesn't save the file due to a problem with the line **"ChDir "C:\My Documents\"**.

What am I missing here?

```
Sub macro()

Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True
WordApp.Activate

Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add

Range("A1:C33").Copy

WordApp.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteRTF, _Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False

WordDoc.PageSetup.LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
WordDoc.PageSetup.TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.4)
WordDoc.PageSetup.BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.5)

ChDir "C:\My Documents\Test"
ActiveDocument.SaveAs "Archief" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & ".docx"

Set WordDoc = Nothing
Set WordApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: does the folder exist?

Comment: I think you might need to use the Environmental variable "userprofile" to access this folder e.g. `MsgBox Environ("userprofile") & "\My Documents"` should display the path to My Documents. `Dim Mypath as string MyPath = Environ("userprofile") & "\My Documents\Test" chDir myPath` would then replace your `ChDir` line

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to **create a variable to include both the path and the name** of the file, like this :

```
Dim FileFullName As String

FileFullName = Environ("userprofile") & "\My Documents\Test" & "\" & "Archief" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & ".docx"
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileFullName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim FileName2        As String

Set appWrd = CreateObject("Word.Application")

   appWrd.DisplayAlerts = False
    FileName2 = Document.Path & "\" & ".docx"
    appWrd.ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=FileName2
```